# Call specific plugin update

Tags: plugins, updates, xml-rpc, remote

I'm looking for way to update specific plugin via [xmlrpc api](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/extended-xml-rpc-api/). There is no exposed any function for do upgrades. I've tried to visit `http://example.com/wp-admin/update.php?action=upgrade-plugin&plugin=plugin%2Fplugin.php&_wpnonce=b606ec1c5a` ("update now" url from admin panel, _wpnonce parameter created by calling `wp_nonce_url`), but it gives only "Are you sure?" message. Sending post request to `update-core.php?action=do-plugin-upgrade` gives me this same: are you sure? Maybe there are some actions or some other ways for do that remotely?